# Firebase - Get all keys where child equals

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to get all push() keys where child equals x.

```
"example_parent" : {
      "push_key_1" : {
        "user_id" : "user_1"
      },
      "push_key_2" : {
        "user_id" : "user_2"
      },
      "push_key_3" : {
        "user_id" : "user_1"
```

For example if where getting all "user_id" that equal "user_1" in the above code it should return push_key_1 and push_key_3.

All help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This would require the use of a Firebase Database query. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I've had a look into Firebase Databse query but i couldn't find anything that works. If there's something that'll get what i'm after done could you reference it for me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it by using simple firebase query

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("example_parent").orderByChild("user_id").equalTo("user_1");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

You can refer the blog if you want to go in depth. The blog is quite old but it would be worth a read.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html